# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show' PySpark

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show'

I am trying to pass any test json file as part of the command line argument. When doing so it treats it as a string , which I dont want but I want it to be treated as a DataFrame so it can show the dataframe with df.show().  I get this error message on the terminal saying AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show’.

```
df = sqlContext.read.json(“tester.json")

def show_data(df):
      df.show()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(‘-I’, ‘—inputfile', required=True , default =df)
args = parser.parse_args()
show_data(args.parameterfile)
```

Comment: Isn't should be `SparkSession` instead of `sqlContext`?

Comment: It work's with the default argument , as soon as i pass a test file via the terminal this will result in the error . So if i do python data.py -i newtest.json it will show 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'show' @AliAzG

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing a *string* to the `show_data` function.

Working code:

```
import argparse

def show_data(input_filename):
    df = sqlContext.read.json(input_filename)
    df.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("filename", help="path of the file of interest")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    show_data(args.filename)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thankyou! That helps. Would you recommend a shorter way of coding this. @Employee

Comment: @Eddy, did the answer solve your problem?  If so, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray check sign on the top-left of the answer